# convert iso time strings to valid momentjs format and compare them

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to compare some times with [momentjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment). These times come from time pickers and use the ISO 8601 format, 24hr hh:mm (more info [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/time-pickers)).

I want to compare the examples "01:45" and "13:36". Using the function `isSameOrBefore` should return me `true`. Unfortunately

```
const valid = moment("01:45").isSameOrBefore("13:36")
```

does not work, because the iso strings use a wrong format. I get the warning

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or
>   ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date()

I tried to go for this

```js
const isoFormat = 'hh:mm'

const first = "01:45"
const second = "13:36"

const firstBeforeSecond = moment(first, isoFormat).isBefore(second, isoFormat)

console.log(firstBeforeSecond)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

but this still fails. The value I get returned is `false` and this is not correct. What is the correct way to compare these time strings?

Comment: I agree with @mplungjan, but if you need moment for some other reason, you should pass a moment object to `isBefore `: `isBefore(moment(second, isoFormat))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using moment for this is huge overkill

Just compare strings

```
"01:45" < "13:36"
```

is true

```
"13:36" === "13:36"
```

is also true

the reason is that in ISO 8601 the strings have the same length and hence will

`"00:00"`  always be the lowest value and `"23:59"` the highest.

This is safe because they stay string and have ":" in them, so will not be cast to number or lose the leading 0s or such

Comment: I think this is "the best" solution, but would you mind adding an explanation why it's possible to compare two strings?  Maybe this is vulnerable to bugs?

Comment: It's simple alphanumeric order (like in printed dictionaries). Coincidentally, it happens to work for hh:mm format.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
moment(first, isoFormat).isBefore(moment(second, isoFormat))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var first = moment('01:45', 'hh:mm');
var second = moment('13:36', 'hh:mm');
console.log(first. isSameOrBefore(second));
```

specifying format will not give any warnings :)